# onclick listener listens to child element click

Tags: javascript, jquery

so I have the following event listener:

```
$("#searchArea dl dd a").on('click',function(e){
    //code
});
```

and I want it to only execute the function when the "a" nodes inside the "dd" nodes (located in the #searchArea div) are clicked, but I also have some "i" nodes inside the "a" nodes. Apparently the event listener also executes the function, when they are clicked.

Here is an example of the structure:

```
<div id="searchArea">
    <dl>
        <dd>
            <a>
                <i></i>
            <a>
        <dd>
    <dl>
</div>
```

Is there any way to prevent the "i" nodes to execute the function if they are clicked?
Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just compare the target of the event:

```
$("#searchArea dl dd a").on('click',function(e){
    if (e.target !== this) return;
    //code
});
```

(Note that this takes advantage of the fact that jQuery normalizes event objects so there'll be a "target" property in all browsers.)